# How to copy paste a part of SQL table in the same table with updated column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have one table TABLE 1

| ID | CLASS | GENDER | SUBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 6A | A1 | ENG |
| A1 | 6A | A1 | MATH |
| A1 | 4A | A1 | COMPUTER |
| A1 | 3A | A1 | GK |

I want to copy and paste the records in the same table(table1) with ID value as A2

Result should be something like this

| ID | CLASS | GENDER | SUBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 6A | A1 | ENG |
| A1 | 6A | A1 | MATH |
| A1 | 4A | A1 | COMPUTER |
| A1 | 3A | A1 | GK |
| A2 | 6A | A1 | ENG |
| A2 | 6A | A1 | MATH |
| A2 | 4A | A1 | COMPUTER |
| A2 | 3A | A1 | GK |

Can someone give the SQL syntax??

what i am doing now is

i made a new table(table2) and copy paste the record and used update() to update the id value A1 TO A2 and then again insert table 2 back into table 1

CREATE TABLE table 2 AS
SELECT *
FROM table 1;

TABLE 2

| ID | CLASS | GENDER | SUBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 6A | A1 | ENG |
| A1 | 6A | A1 | MATH |
| A1 | 4A | A1 | COMPUTER |
| A1 | 3A | A1 | GK |

Then,
Used
Update table2
SET ID = 'A2'
Where ID= 'A1';

| ID | CLASS | GENDER | SUBJECT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | 6A | A1 | ENG |
| A2 | 6A | A1 | MATH |
| A2 | 4A | A1 | COMPUTER |
| A2 | 3A | A1 | GK |

Then,
INSERT INTO table1 select * From table2;

But it is long process i want a shortcut of this and not create any extra table and all

just one syntax or max 2

because i want to reduce the time

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`?

Comment: As per question guidelines, pls do not post images

Comment: everything is working just that i dont want to create extra table to update the value of ID..........can you can click on the image to understand my question better

Comment: Please tag your rdbms

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to duplicate the existing A1 rows with a new value for ID right?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (
    ID
    ,CLASS
    ,GENDER
    ,SUBJECT
    )
SELECT 'A2'
    ,CLASS
    ,GENDER
    ,SUBJECT
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID = 'A1'
```

Answer (score -1):

As @NicoHaase suggested you, to accomplish this you could use INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Something like...

```
INSERT INTO [Table1]
SELECT 'A2', [CLASS], [GENDER], [SUBJECT]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE [ID] = 'A1'
```

Comment: That query does not look like one that you could use in MySQL

Comment: Probably you are right, this is because I work with SQL Server, where it would work, that's why I wrote "something like..."